How Do I Make An Image To Have Fixed Width And Auto Height in Flutter
I am trying to make an Image have a fixed width but the height should be auto. More like a responsive image.
Here is the code I wrote but it is not working
Image.file(
   imageFile!,
   height: auto,
   width: 200,
),


Just don’t provide height and leave it like this:
Image.file(
   imageFile!,
   width: 200,
),

Flutter will automatically adjust the height for you

Didn't work, even the width of the image wasn't affected. What am I doing wrongly?

It depends on what type of widget your Image is surrounded by (what is it’s parent). If it is in a Row, Column, ListView it will take the width you have given to this image, but if it is in Expanded for example, it will take Expanded’s width

It is wrapped in a container. Here is the code
Container(
width: 200.0,
height: 200.0,
child: Image.file(
imageFile!,
width: 100.0,
),
),

It will have Container’s size then. Wrap it with column or specify desired with in your Container and add fit: BoxFit.contain to your image

i suggest the next:
Container(
width : 200,
child: Image.asset(
  'You Image',
   width : 200,
   fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
 )
)

Don't impose any constraints on height, so it's freely changes its height while having a fixed width.
The height will depend on the main dimensions of the image.
